# R Importing ARIMA model outputs to use in forecast

Tags: r, arima, forecast

I have undertaken ARIMA modelling using the auto.arima function for 91 models. The outputs are sitting in a list of lists.

The structure of the outputs for one model looks like the following:

```
    List of 19
      $ coef     : Named num [1:8] -3.17e-01 -3.78e-01 -8.02e-01 -5.39e+04 -1.33e+05 ...
      ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:8] "ar1" "ar2" "ma1" "Price.Diff" ...
      $ sigma2   : num 6.37e+10
      $ var.coef : num [1:8, 1:8] 1.84e-02 8.90e-03 -7.69e-03 -8.80e+02 2.83e+03 ...
      ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      .. ..$ : chr [1:8] "ar1" "ar2" "ma1" "Price.Diff" ...
      .. ..$ : chr [1:8] "ar1" "ar2" "ma1" "Price.Diff" ...
      $ mask     : logi [1:8] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
      $ loglik   : num -1189
      $ aic      : num 2395
      $ arma     : int [1:7] 2 1 0 0 1 1 0
      $ residuals: Time-Series [1:87] from 1 to 87: 1810 -59503 263294 240970 94842 ...
      $ call     : language auto.arima(y = x[, 2], stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE, xreg = x[, 3:ncol(x)], x = list(x = c(1856264.57,| __truncated__ ...
      $ series   : chr "x[, 2]"
      $ code     : int 0
      $ n.cond   : int 0
      $ nobs     : int 86
      $ model    :List of 10
      ..$ phi  : num [1:2] -0.317 -0.378
      ..$ theta: num -0.802
      ..$ Delta: num 1
      ..$ Z    : num [1:3] 1 0 1
      ..$ a    : num [1:3] -599787 284456 1887763
      ..$ P    : num [1:3, 1:3] 0.00 0.00 -4.47e-23 0.00 3.33e-16 ...
      ..$ T    : num [1:3, 1:3] -0.317 -0.378 1 1 0 ...
      ..$ V    : num [1:3, 1:3] 1 -0.802 0 -0.802 0.643 ...
      ..$ h    : num 0
      ..$ Pn   : num [1:3, 1:3] 1.00 -8.02e-01 -1.83e-23 -8.02e-01 6.43e-01 ...
      $ bic      : num 2417
      $ aicc     : num 2398
      $ xreg     : Time-Series [1:87, 1:5] from 1 to 87: -0.866 -0.466 -1.383 -0.999 -0.383 ...
      ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      .. ..$ : NULL
      .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "Price.Diff" "Easter" "Christmas" "High.Week" ...
      $ x        : Time-Series [1:87] from 1 to 87: 1856265 1393925 2200962 2209996 2161707 ...
      $ fitted   : Time-Series [1:87] from 1 to 87: 1854455 1453429 1937668 1969026 2066864 ...
      - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "ARIMA" "forecast_ARIMA" "Arima"
```

When printed the output looks as follows:

```
Series: x[, 2] 
Regression with ARIMA(2,1,1) errors 

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2      ma1      Price.Diff      Easter      Christmas      High.Week      Low.Week
         -0.3170  -0.3777  -0.8017  -53931.11       -133187.55  -53541.62      -347146.59     216202.71
s.e.      0.1356   0.1319   0.1069   28195.33        68789.25    23396.62      -74115.78      66881.15

sigma^2 estimated as 6.374e+10:  log likelihood=-1188.69
AIC=2395.38   AICc=2397.75   BIC=2417.47
```

I have written the following to export my models to text file format:

```
# export model outputs to newly created folder
for(i in 1:length(ts_outputs)){
 sink(paste0(names(ts_outputs[i]), ".txt"))
 print(ts_outputs[i])
 sink()
}
```

This works, to view the model outputs themselves, however I need to be able to import the model outputs back into R to use them to forecast out my time series' forward.

I am assuming that I need to put them back into the original structure once re-imported.

Is there a certain package that has already been written to do this?

Are text files the way to go for the original exporting?

I believe the following is the source code from the forecast package which writes the outputs (https://rdrr.io/github/ttnsdcn/forecast-package/src/R/arima.R):

```
        if (length(x$coef) > 0) {
                cat("\nCoefficients:\n")
                coef <- round(x$coef, digits=digits)
                if (se && nrow(x$var.coef)) {
                    ses <- rep(0, length(coef))
                    ses[x$mask] <- round(sqrt(diag(x$var.coef)), digits=digits)
                    coef <- matrix(coef, 1, dimnames=list(NULL, names(coef)))
                    coef <- rbind(coef, s.e.=ses)
                }
                print.default(coef, print.gap=2)
            }
            cm <- x$call$method
            if (is.null(cm) || cm != "CSS")
            {
                cat("\nsigma^2 estimated as ", format(x$sigma2, digits=digits),
                    ":  log likelihood=", format(round(x$loglik, 2)),"\n",sep="")
                npar <- length(x$coef) + 1
                nstar <- length(x$residuals) - x$arma[6] - x$arma[7]*x$arma[5]
                bic <- x$aic + npar*(log(nstar) - 2)
                aicc <- x$aic + 2*npar*(nstar/(nstar-npar-1) - 1)
                cat("AIC=", format(round(x$aic, 2)), sep="")
                cat("   AICc=", format(round(aicc, 2)), sep="")
                cat("   BIC=", format(round(bic, 2)), "\n",sep="")
            }
            else cat("\nsigma^2 estimated as ", format(x$sigma2, digits=digits),
                ":  part log likelihood=", format(round(x$loglik, 2)),
                "\n", sep="")
            invisible(x)
        }
```

Appreciate any direction/advice.

Comment: Do you want to store them so that you don't have to run the estimations again? In that case, how about just saving it as an .RData file? `save(ts_outputs, file = "ts_outputs.RData")`

Comment: [`saveRDS`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/readRDS)

Comment: @YalDan the end goal is two have two vba macros to call two separate R scripts, one for estimation, one for forecasting.

Comment: Just for my understanding: you fit the models with the `auto.arima` function. Then, you export the parameters and want to process them in another r-script, right?

Comment: @YalDan that is correct. The reason they are separated is the models won't need to be run often, say every few months. The assumptions underpinning the forecasts can be tweaked weekly. Thats why I need to be able to run forecasts with quick tweaks to assumptions, using existing models.

Comment: Do you need the .txt-files to perform analyses outside R or are all steps performed inside R? If the forecasting is also done R-internal and you don't modify the parameters after export, I suggest you save the list object as outined in my first comment. You can then easily load the file again with `load("ts_outputs.RData")`.

Comment: No all calculations are performed within R. I will try the save/load functions that you have recommended.  Thank you for your help

Comment: @YalDan works like a charm! Appreciate the help

Comment: Glad I could help :)